# Program exits when the threads finishes their jobs but does not wait for the background worker to complete its job

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to C# multi-threading and I need assistance with the following problem. In my below code, I start three new threads that reads data from SQL in a loop and I also start a background worker. After 30 seconds the worker sets the static property `Flag` of the `TestClass` to `false` which makes the 3 instances of the `TestClass` running in the three threads to sleep for 3 seconds and then exit the loop. While the threads sleep for 3 seconds, the worker asynchronously starts a new thread that should sleep for 50 seconds (`doing something...`). However, I notice that, as soon as the three threads exit the for-loop the complete program exits. I would like to await until the bg worker completes its work. Can someone please provide a solution on how can I make my program wait and not exit?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StaticPropertyExperiment
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void StartThreads()
        {
            var t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(() => new TestClass().SQLTest(100));
            t1.Start();
            var t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(() => new TestClass().SQLTest(100));
            t2.Start();
            var t3 = new System.Threading.Thread(() => new TestClass().SQLTest(100));
            t3.Start();
        }

        private static async void work_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);

                if (TestClass.Flag)
                {
                    TestClass.SetupFlag(false);
                    Console.WriteLine("watining to end threads");
                    Console.WriteLine("starting async process");
                    await Task.Run(() => new TestClass().SQLTest(5));                    
                }
                else
                {
                    TestClass.SetupFlag(true);
                    StartThreads();
                }                
                Console.WriteLine("Async Completed");
            }
        }

        private static void StartBackgroundWorker()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting bg worker..");
            BackgroundWorker work = new BackgroundWorker();
            work.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(work_DoWork);
            work.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartThreads();
            StartBackgroundWorker();
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public static bool Flag = true;

        public static void SetupFlag(bool flag)
        {
            Flag = flag;
        }

        public void SQLTest(int num)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                if (Flag)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"I --> {i}");
                    GetLatestAttributeValuesFromLastCycleEndTime();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"num --> {num}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Ended");
                    if (num != 5)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3 * 1000);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("doing something ...");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50 * 1000);
                    }
                    //Console.ReadKey();
                }            
            }
        }
```

Comment: The Backgroundworker does not block terminating a program. So you need to either **not use it** or manually wait for its work to complete, for example with a ManualResetEvent or something like that.

Comment: Unrelated: There is a [`Sleep(TimeSpan)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-6.0#system-threading-thread-sleep(system-timespan)) which is much more readable. Like `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));`.

Comment: *Don't* use the obsolete BGW in the first place. It's been completely replaced by async/await and Task.Run since 2012. If you want to execute code in the background though, a far better option would be to use a Timer

Comment: ^^ What Panagiotis says plus: **do not mix** BGW, Threading _and_ async/Task. Doesn't end well, guaranteed.

Comment: Using `BackgroundWorker` really makes only sense in WinForms projects and only there, if you need the designer support to configure its properties and event callbacks. In all other cases please use async/await.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Using a timer still does not solve the problem.

Comment: What *is* the problem? Almost all of this code is what you think the solution would look like. It's unclear what you're trying to solve though. There's no reason to use raw threads, no reason to use `Thread.Sleep` and definitely no reason to use unsynchronized fields. For example, if you want to cancel background jobs, use a CancellationTokenSource with a timeout, eg `_cts=new CancellationTokenSource(30000);`. After that, all background threads can check the CTS's CancellationToken property to see whether they should exit. Unlike a static field, CancellationToken is thread-safe

Comment: You can start multiple background jobs with `Task.Run` and await all of them with `await Task.WhenAll()`. You can delay *without* blocking the current thread with `await Task.Delay()`